# Beginner doing an OOP Project vb.net

Tags: vb.net, oop

Alright, so I have edited my code and now when I'm trying to run it I'm getting this error.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "Holden 308" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
Additional information: Conversion from string "JD Catepillar Track" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

So both errors are happening in the HeavyStockItem class with the overloading New classes. Wondering if anyone can help me out with understanding why it's doing that.

> ```
> Option Strict On 
>
> Public Class Form1
> Dim StockItem1 As StockItem
> Dim StockItem2 As CarEngine
> Dim StockItem3 As CarEngine
> Dim StockItem4 As StockItem
> Dim StockItem5 As HeavyStockItem
>
> Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
>     StockItem1 = New StockItem("Screwdriver Set", 42)
>
>     StockItem2 = New CarEngine(8025, "Madza B6T", 1252, 800, "Z4537298D")
>
>     'StockItem3 = New CarEngine("Holden 308", 958, 1104, "P74623854S")
>
>     StockItem4 = New StockItem(8002, "Trolley Jack", 127)
>
>     'StockItem5 = New HeavyStockItem("JD Catepillar Track", 3820, 2830)
> End Sub
>
> Private Sub btnListStock_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnListStock.Click
>     txtOutput.Clear()
>     ShowOutput(StockItem1)
>     ShowOutput(StockItem2)
>     'ShowOutput(StockItem3)
>     ShowOutput(StockItem4)
>     'ShowOutput(StockItem5)
> End Sub
>
> Public Sub ShowOutput(ByVal Output As StockItem)
>     txtOutput.Text &= Output.Print()
>     txtOutput.Text &= vbCrLf
> End Sub
>
> Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnd.Click
>     End
> End Sub 
> End Class
> ```

---

> ```
> Public Class StockItem
>
> Friend CostPrice As Integer
> Friend LastStockNumber As Integer
> Friend StockNumber As Integer
> Friend Description As String
> Friend Shared LastStockItem As Integer = 10000
>
> Overridable Function Print() As String
>     Dim Result As String = ""
>     Result &= "Stock No: " & StockNumber
>     Result &= vbCrLf
>     Result &= "Description: " & Description
>     Result &= vbCrLf
>     Result &= "Cost Price: " & CostPrice
>     Result &= vbCrLf
>     Return Result
> End Function
>
> Public Sub New(ByVal StockNumber As Integer, Description As String, ByVal CostPrice As Integer)
>     Me.New(Description, CostPrice)
>     Me.StockNumber = StockNumber
> End Sub
>
> Public Sub New(ByVal Description As String, ByVal CostPrice As Integer)
>     LastStockNumber += Rnd()
>     Me.StockNumber = LastStockNumber
>     Me.Description = Description
>     Me.CostPrice = CostPrice
> End Sub
>
> Public Sub GetCostPrice()
>
> End Sub
> End Class
> ```

---

> ```
> Public Class HeavyStockItem
> Inherits Assessment3.StockItem
> Friend Weight As Integer
>
> Public Function GetWeight() As String
>     Return Me.GetWeight
> End Function
>
> Public Sub New(ByVal StockNumber As Integer, ByVal Description As String, ByVal CostPrice As Integer, ByVal Weight As Integer)
>     MyBase.New(StockNumber, Description, CostPrice)
>     Me.Weight = Weight
> End Sub
>
> Public Sub New(ByVal Description As String, ByVal CostPrice As Integer, ByVal Weight As Integer)
>     MyBase.New(Description, CostPrice, Weight)'' Where the error is occurring
>     LastStockNumber += Rnd()
>     Me.StockNumber = LastStockNumber
> End Sub
> End Class
> ```

---

> ```
> Public Class CarEngine
> Inherits Assessment3.HeavyStockItem
>
> Friend EngineNumber As String
>
> Overrides Function Print() As String
>     Dim Result As String = ""
>     Result &= "Stock No: " & StockNumber
>     Result &= vbCrLf
>     Result &= "Description: " & Description
>     Result &= vbCrLf
>     Result &= "Cost Price: " & CostPrice
>     Result &= vbCrLf
>     Result &= "Weight: " & Weight
>     Result &= vbCrLf
>     Result &= "Engine Number: " & EngineNumber
>     Result &= vbCrLf
>     Return Result
> End Function
>
> Public Sub New(ByVal StockNumber As Integer, ByVal Description As String, ByVal CostPrice As Integer, ByVal Weight As Integer, ByVal EngineNumber As String)
>     MyBase.New(StockNumber, Description, CostPrice, Weight)
>     Me.EngineNumber = EngineNumber
> End Sub
>
> Public Sub New(ByVal Description As String, ByVal CostPrice As Integer, ByVal Weight As Integer, ByVal EngineNumber As String)
>     MyBase.New(Description, CostPrice, Weight)
>     LastStockNumber += Rnd()
>     Me.StockNumber = LastStockNumber
>     End Sub
>
> End Class
> ```

Any help provided would be great. Just thought it'd be easier to provide the full code instead of just putting only the little bits that I really needed, incase if people asked about the other parts of the code. Thanks for reading and providing help if you provided help.

Comment: Can you please summarize what the concrete problems are?

Comment: I can't see what your actual question is...

Comment: Well, my main question is trying to get the constructor in both the CarEngine class and the HeavyStockItem. Where I have commented that it needs a MyClass/MyBase.New because it's not accessible to the "Sub New" so it can't be called with no arguments

Comment: You have a problem with understanding types.  Put `Option Strict On` at the top of the source code file and recompile your program.  You are going to get a lot of error messages, it will take you a while.  Fixing those errors however will give you a *lot* more insight in types.

Comment: @HansPassant I am able to get 3 out of the 5 results working it's just those 2, StockItem3 and StockItem5 that are causing the crash, see the thing is. I think it's trying to call the StockItemNumber when it should just be automatically input and I can't seem to get it to just bypass the stocknumber, if you get what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

Since your code was confusing to me I relied mostly on the exception.

It basically says that it cant convert the string into an integer. Here's something that could cause the same problem.

`Dim Number As String = "10"`

`'Few Lines of code.`

`Number = 11`
whats basically happening is that when you declare a variable as a string the value of it HAS to be in double quotes as you see when it was declared. Now then we try to change the value to 11 while adding no double quotes, therefor it thought you were changing it to an integer and gave the error.

I looked through the code and saw this, maybe this is causing it:

`Me.Description = Description` <--- No quotes!!!

I'm probably wrong though since i didn't really understand the code.